# Custom font inside viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to use a custom font on my viewPager (custom font for the tabs titles). Below is the code I am using to initiate the tabs and fragments. I have searched on google for the last 4 hours but nothing matches what I want to do. Basically I want to use a custom font that I have inside my `assets` folder. How can I implement this to the code I have. The main problem I am facing is that I can't use `.setTypeface` on a `view`. Note: the code bellow works with no problems.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, View.OnClickListener{

    //tabs
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabs = {"Home", "Messages", "Profile", "Logout"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //other code here...

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new AdapterManager(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener((ActionBar.TabListener) this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position){actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);}
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2){}
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0){}
        });
   }
}
```

AdapterManeger.java

```
public class AdapterManager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public AdapterManager(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new HomeFragment();
            case 1:
                return new MessageFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ProfileFragment();
            case 3:
                return new LogoutFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</FrameLayout>
```

Update:
I tried this:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontawesome.ttf");
View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.viewLayout);
view.setTypeface(font);

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <view
        android:id="@+id/viewLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </view>



</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `main problem I am facing is that I can't use .setTypeface on a view` on which view or where you are trying to set typeface ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I tried adding a `<View>` around `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` and use `.setTypeface()` but that did not work. So I deleted that code.

Comment: Please also add code which you have tried in post for more help

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK question updated. The app crashes when I have the `View` aroundthe `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`